# Objective-C: How to keep an application in dock?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to keep my application in dock, however I am not able to do this.
[image]

**How I am trying to do?**

```
@interface UserDefaultsHelper : NSUserDefaults

- (BOOL)addApplicationToDock:(NSString *)path;

- (BOOL)removeApplicationFromDock:(NSString *)name;

@end


@implementation UserDefaultsHelper

- (BOOL)addApplicationToDock:(NSString *)path {
    NSDictionary *domain = [self persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.dock"];
    NSArray *apps = [domain objectForKey:@"persistent-apps"];
    NSArray *matchingApps = [apps filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS %@", @"tile-data.file-data._CFURLString", path]];
    if ([matchingApps count] == 0) {
        NSMutableDictionary *newDomain = [domain mutableCopy];
        NSMutableArray *newApps = [apps mutableCopy];
        NSDictionary *app = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:path, @"_CFURLString", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"_CFURLStringType", nil] forKey:@"file-data"] forKey:@"tile-data"];
        [newApps addObject:app];
        [newDomain setObject:newApps forKey:@"persistent-apps"];
        [self setPersistentDomain:newDomain forName:@"com.apple.dock"];
        return [self synchronize];
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)removeApplicationFromDock:(NSString *)name {
    NSDictionary *domain = [self persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.dock"];
    NSArray *apps = [domain objectForKey:@"persistent-apps"];
    NSArray *newApps = [apps filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not %K CONTAINS %@", @"tile-data.file-data._CFURLString", name]];
    if (![apps isEqualToArray:newApps]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *newDomain = [domain mutableCopy];
        [newDomain setObject:newApps forKey:@"persistent-apps"];
        [self setPersistentDomain:newDomain forName:@"com.apple.dock"];
        return [self synchronize];
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

I found the above code from here. [Code Source](http://www.danandcheryl.com/2011/02/how-to-modify-the-dock-or-login-items-on-os-x)

the above code is getting compiled and running, however it's adding the application in the application's dock.

I am a newbie here. Please be lenient towards me as I do not have OS level of knowledge.

Many thanks in advance for your help and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided in question is correct the only problem was that the dock was not getting refreshed. So we just need to refresh the `DOCK`

In order to refresh dock I am calling a terminal command from obj-c

**Terminal Command** `killall dock`

```
    ....code...
    [self runCommand:@"killall Dock"];   
} 

-(NSString*)runCommand:(NSString*)commandToRun;
{
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"-c" ,
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commandToRun],
                          nil];
    NSLog(@"run command: %@",commandToRun);
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *output;
    output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return output;
}
```